# How to use Spanish National shift table in twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

When using the Twilo API to send Spanish language SMS messages how do I send using the National Shift Table for Spanish (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38#National_language_shift_tables). Without that some Spanish messages end up going out as UCS-2 instead of GSM-7.